# How to run openssh-server compiled from source

Tags: 14.04, openssh, sshd

I have compiled `openssh` source using 
`./configure`
`make` and
`make install`

Now it has compiled and installed binaries, config files and the server at

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/etc
/usr/local/sbin
```

what's next?. How do I start the `ssh` server and start connecting to it?

Answer (score 5):

I guess, you must have found the answer by now.
but if not then run the following:

```
# sudo /usr/local/sbin/sshd
```

In some distributions, the `sshd` file will be located elsewhere, e.g., `/usr/sbin/sshd`

This will start the openssh server with default settings, but in a few cases it will show an error:

```
privilege separation user sshd does not exist
```

To resolve this error, run the following commands before compiling OpenSSH:

```
sudo install -v -m700 -d /var/lib/sshd
sudo chown -v root:sys /var/lib/sshd
sudo groupadd sshd
sudo useradd  -c 'sshd PrivSep' -d /var/lib/sshd -g sshd -s /bin/false -u 50 sshd
```

Comment: @DavidFoerster - Yes. I have modified the answer with the 'proper' way to avoid that error.

Answer (score 0):

My preferred way to us a locally built version of a standard package is to `apt-get source` the Ubuntu version of the package, update the source and build a `.deb` from there and install that.
This helps you to get all `init` scripts and configurations in line with the rest of your system.

Answer (score -1):

see if you can do `sudo service ssh start`, if it does and you want it to run on startup you can also do `sudo update-rc.d ssh defaults` to always run it on startup.

then from another machine (linux/mac) try ssh username@machine-ip. On windows you can use putty providing machine ip.

Comment: It says unrecognized service with 'sudo service ssh start'. I can see a file named 'sshd' in /usr/local/sbin. I presume it's the server and this needs to be started as a service. Should I update my PATH or something? How does 'service' command know about a new ssh service installed on the system?